# Pulling random records for each pair of values an another table SQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm looking to pull 2 random student names in table 1 for each Class-Teacher pair in Table 2. I looked into using

Table 1

| Class | Teacher |
| --- | --- |
| Math | Mr. Smith |
| Math | Mrs. Kim |
| Science | Mr. Smith |
| Science | Mrs. Kim |

Table 2

| Student |
| --- |
| Matt |
| Jess |
| Tom |
| Sally |
| Rod |
| Nikki |

Final Example

| Class | Teacher | Student |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Math | Mr. Smith | Matt |
| Math | Mr. Smith | Sally |
| Math | Mrs. Kim | Nikki |
| Math | Mrs. Kim | Rod |
| Science | Mr. Smith | Matt |
| Science | Mr. Smith | Jess |
| Science | Mrs. Kim | Tom |
| Science | Mrs. Kim | Rod |

Comment: Do you actually need them to be random, or just *any* student will do?

Comment: They need to to be random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RANDOM()` to sort the rows randombly and then pick the first two.

For example:

```
select
  a.*, x.*
from table1 a,
lateral (
  select  *
  from table2
  order by length(a.class) * 0 + random()
  limit 2
) x
```

Result:

```
 class    teacher    student 
 -------- ---------- ------- 
 Math     Mr. Smith  Matt    
 Math     Mr. Smith  Jess    
 Math     Mrs. Kim   Nikki   
 Math     Mrs. Kim   Rod     
 Science  Mr. Smith  Rod     
 Science  Mr. Smith  Jess    
 Science  Mrs. Kim   Tom     
 Science  Mrs. Kim   Jess
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cS4LqNTgtX3MtHNhAFyBq9/0). Please note the results change every time you run the query.